# How to use tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary and tft.tfidf correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-idf, tensorflow-transform

I try to use tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary and tft.tfidf to compute tfidf in my jupyter notebook. However I always get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'compute_and_apply_vocabulary/vocabulary/Placeholder' with dtype string
     [[node compute_and_apply_vocabulary/vocabulary/Placeholder (defined at C:\Users\secsi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_
```

but the placeholder type is actually string.

Here is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft

with tf.Session() as sess:
    documents = [
        "a b c d e",
        "f g h i j",
        "k l m n o",
        "p q r s t",
    ]
    documents_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
    tokens = tf.compat.v1.string_split(documents_tensor)
    compute_vocab = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(tokens, vocab_filename='vocab.txt')

    global_vars_init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    tabel_init = tf.tables_initializer()


    sess.run([global_vars_init, tabel_init])
    token2ids = sess.run(tfidf, feed_dict={documents_tensor: documents})
    print(f"token2ids: {token2ids}")
```

Version:

- tensorflow: 1.14
- tensorflow-transform: 0.14

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can't use the Operations of `Tensorflow Transform` like `tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary` directly, unlike `Tensorflow` Operations, which can be used directly in a `Session`.

For us to use the Operations of `Tensorflow Transform`, we must run them in a `preprocessing_fn` which should be then passed to `tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset`.

In your case, as you have Text Data, your code can be modified as shown below:

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):

    """inputs is our dataset"""
    documents = inputs['documents']

    tokens = tf.compat.v1.string_split(documents)
    compute_vocab = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(tokens)
    # Add one for the oov bucket created by compute_and_apply_vocabulary.
    review_bow_indices, review_weight = tft.tfidf(compute_vocab,
                                                  VOCAB_SIZE + 1)
    return {
        REVIEW_KEY: review_bow_indices,
        REVIEW_WEIGHT_KEY: review_weight,
        LABEL_KEY: inputs[LABEL_KEY]
    }

(transformed_train_data, transformed_metadata), transform_fn = 
((train_data, RAW_DATA_METADATA) | 'AnalyzeAndTransform' >>
tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(preprocessing_fn))
```

You can refer this [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/examples/sentiment_example.py) for an example on how to perform Data Pre-Processing using `Tensorflow Transform` on a Text Dataset (Sentiment Analysis).

If you feel this answer is useful, kindly accept this answer and/or up vote it. Thanks.